# Only show notifications if tab is closed

Tags: javascript, dom, conditional-statements, service-worker, web-push

I have a node.js push notification server (with websocket server also running on it), and it is sending push events whenever the websocket server receives a message. The problem with this is that no matter what happens, when the websocket server gets a message, it broadcasts a message no matter what. While this is fine, it can become a problem for clients actively on the website, because the notification is unnecessary as the person can already see what happened, and the serviceworker can't access the DOM so it can't tell if the window is open or not. I tried the `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage` method to tell the server to either "stop" the notification service, or "start" the notification service in the below code. It all seems correct and I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't seem to be working as it shows a notification whether the window is open or not.

(main.js)

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
        Notification.requestPermission((permit)=>{
            console.log(permit);
        });
    }
    subscribe().catch(error => console.error(error));
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("stop"); //Tell serviceWorker to not show notifications
}
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("start"); //Tell serviceWorker that it is allowed show notifications
}
function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');const rawData = window.atob(base64);const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);}return outputArray;}
const publicVapidKey = <key here>;
async function subscribe() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        //register serviceworker
        const register = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
            scope: '/'
        });
        //subscribe to notifications
        const subscription = await register.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey),
        });
        //send subscription to server
        await fetch('http://remoteserver.com:8080/subscribe', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    } else {console.error('Service workers are not supported in this browser');}
}
```

(sw.js)

```
var allowed;
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data == "stop") {
        allowed = false;
    } else if (event.data == "start") {
        allowed = true;
    }
});
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    if (allowed == true) {
        const data = event.data.json();
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
            body: data.body,
            icon: data.icon
        });
    }
});
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The service worker is a mediary between your client app and server.

If the client is determined to be active (up to you to make that determination in your code — see links below), it should communicate to the sw informing it as such.

You can implement a heartbeat/ping-pong between the sw and your client (not unlike websockets) that occurs at an interval, and if the client fails to respond (or responds in an enumeration that isn't "active"), then your sw will know, and can respond appropriately (whether that's simply not emitting the notifications received from the server, or unsubscribing entirely, etc.)

More reading: [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), [Document.hasFocus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus), etc.